# How to ignore uppercase using start_with?

Tags: ruby, string

Is there a better way to ignore uppercase than this?

```
"Hello".start_with?("hell","Hell") #=> true
```

I want to check if a string element in an array starts with another string ignoring uppercase, like  `LIKE %` in MySQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
'Hello'.upcase.start_with?('HELL')
```

Another approach to the same problem. That's equivalent to do something like `UPPER(column) like 'SOMETHING%'` in SQL.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [regular expression](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html) with [`String#=~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E):

```
"Hello" =~ /^hell/i    #=> 0
"hELLO" =~ /^hell/i    #=> 0
"world" =~ /^hell/i    #=> nil
```

Since `0` is *truthy* and `nil` is *falsy* this can be used in an `if` clause:

```
if str =~ /^hell/i
  # starts with hell
end
```

Comment: Simple regular expressions are much more CPU and memory intensive than simple string operations so you are better off using simple string operations (e.g. begins_with).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is to use Ruby's regex matching with ignore case flag:

```
'Hello'.match /^hell/i
```

The '^' designates the start of the string. Without it would match 'hell' anywhere in the string. And the last 'i' is just a regex flag to indicate matching with ignore case set.

You can find more info on Ruby Regex API here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html